# SSIS 2005 dtsx Objects Migration to SQL Server 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I have heaps of dtsx objects on a file system (2005 compatible), Some of objects have `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` previously setup by some developer but no password available.

I need to migrate all the dtsx objects to SQL Server 2012, but I am getting error as I try to migrate which is expected.

Could you guys suggest a way to change or overwrite `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` of a dtsx object on a file system?

I do not want to open object in Visual Studio change the permission level as I am talking about 400+ objects migration.

Comment: just a tip: try to convert from 2005 to 2008 and then to 2012 ssis...

Comment: `EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey` is a supported encryption type in 2012.  What is the error that you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an external XML configuration file for this project?

In that case, add this key to the file:

```
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Properties[PackagePassword]" ValueType="String"><ConfiguredValue></ConfiguredValue></Configuration>
<Configuration ConfiguredType="Property" Path="\Package.Properties[ProtectionLevel]" ValueType="Int32"> ConfiguredValue>2</ConfiguredValue></Configuration>
```

NOTE:

1. In the 2nd key-value pair, the value 2 stands for 'EncryptSensitiveWithPassword'. But you are giving an empty value for the package password in the 1st key so it should not cause any problem (it didn't give any problems for me).
2. But if it does not work, try changing the value of the 2nd key from '2' to '0' which stands for 'DontSaveSensitive' and try again.

Please mark my post as answer if it helps :)